# Is company spotlight payed per job listing?

Tags: discussion, jobs

On Careers 2.0 is company spotlight payed per job listing? If that's the case, then how are collisions like the following handled?

- Someone has 10 job listings pending. If he purchases company spotlight he pays $600  * 10 = $6000.
- Someone has 1 job listings pending. If he purchases company spotlight he pays $600  * 1 = $600. Now he puchases 9 job listing more.

In both cases someone has 10 job listings pending, however he pays $6000 for the company spotlight in the first case and $600 in the second case.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why the CV? This is [careers] related..

Comment: Oh, this is about Careers... Confusing ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spotlight is a separate product. Pricing is a flat $600 (at time of this answer), regardless of how many listings somebody has (although you need to have at least one listing live for the spotlight to show).