# Careers 2.0: Company Spotlight links to 0 jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This looks like a bug:

The company "Which?" is appearing in the "company spotlight" sidebar. If you click the logo or the "[View which? job listings »](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/which??a=6c)" link you arrive at the job search page which has zero results.

This answer to the "[Q: Is company spotlight payed per job listing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131356/is-company-spotlight-payed-per-job-listing)" question indicates that a company needs to have at least one live job listing to appear in the "company spotlight" sidebar:
[A: Is company spotlight payed per job listing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131369/166045)

---

**This Bug Report is not about the encoding of the link**
The link encoding discussed in the comments was a red herring.

The links I copied had the encoded question mark "?". The reason they weren't encoded after I added them to my question is that the system unencodes the entity if you use the "Hyperlink button" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+L to add a link to the selected text. See this question for further info:
[Hyperlink button breaks some URLs when automatically undoing URL encoding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153278/hyperlink-button-breaks-some-urls-when-automatically-undoing-url-encoding)

---

**The actual bug that was being reported:**
The bug is that companies are appearing in the "company spotlight" sidebar even when they don't have any job listings. The links under the company info in the sidebar say:
View "Company Name" job listings »

Which means that there should be job listings. See original question at top for link to answer that says a company must have at least on job listing to appear in the sidebar.

**This bug Is Reproducible**
By hitting reload numerous times on the [careers home page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), I was just able to find instances of three companies being shown in the sidebar even though they don't have any job listings. **You need to be logged in to see this. When I tried without logging in, the company in the sidebar never changed even though I reloaded the page numerous times.**

I've taken screen shots of the home page with each company in the sidebar and then of the jobs listing page that is linked to from the sidebar:

[image: Which? in home page sidebar]
[image: Which? empty jobs page]
[image: Palantir in home page sidebar]
[image: Palantir empty jobs page]
[image: Two Sigma in home page sidebar]
[image: Two Sigma empty jobs page]

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Stand by. Follow up: Where did you get that link? It appears to be encoding correctly for me: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/which%3f

Comment: @MattSherman I get the bug too with both links.

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk yes, those links are broken, but we cannot find out where those links were being generated. Both the home page and jobs list page correctly encode the ? character.

Comment: @mjibson I'm not seeing that company anymore, I believe that it was on the search results page, though it may have been on my favorites page (I just checked both). The URL encoding doesn't explain why it appeared in the sidebar to begin with, does it? See the addition to my question.

Comment: @mjibson Was this a bug? Can you post a short answer so I can close it?

Comment: @MattSherman Was this a bug? Can you post a short answer so I can close it?

Comment: While trying to reproduce the encoding bug, we found the zero displayed jobs bug. It's because some jobs are only displayed in some countries, so you aren't seeing any because you're not in Europe. We'll change it so company spotlights only show if there are jobs for that company that will be shown to you.

Comment: Good to hear, I followed up because it occurred to me that the encoding might have been messed up when I added it to the question and when I tested it, that was the case. I flagged the question to have it reopened, not sure if you can clear that flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. We had code to do this (not show you company spotlights for companies with no jobs in your region), but it had a bug of the form: `a && b || c` that should have been `a && (b || c)`.

Comment: I'm still seeing Two Sigma. Tried clearing my cache just in case, but it still shows up in the home page sidebar and there aren't any jobs listed when you follow the link. I'm in New Jersey and the section below "featured jobs" says "jobs near Jackson". Not sure if my particular location might hold a clue, including it just in case.

Comment: I think that is yet another bug. At least Which? isn't showing up for North America anymore, though. I'll continue to look into this.

Comment: Should I accept this answer and open a different bug question for the Two Sigma bug?

Comment: Nope, I fixed it. Data issue, not a bug. Thanks for the reminder, though.

Comment: I just checked the home page and after reloading it a few times, I got Two Sigma in the side panel. The link still leads to a page that say "0 Two Sigma jobs" at the top and doesn't contain any job listings.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both home page and job search page now yield correct links to the two sigma page. Could have possibly been a cache issue on our servers.

Comment: Awesomeness, I'm now seeing six listings for Two Sigma. Great job getting the issues resolved and keeping me (the client?) updated.